# How to include my angular controller into my ui-router model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am a newbie in angular. I want to include my controller lib/AppController.js into my ui-router module to display on the index page. Kindly help

here is my 
index.html

```
<body>
   <div ui-view="home"></div>  
</body>
```

Appmodule.js

```
var weatherapp = angular.module('weatherapp', ["ui.router",])
    weatherapp.config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: "",
            views: {
                "home": {
                    templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
                    controller: 'weatherCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
    })
```

Appcontroller.js
    (function (window) {

```
    'use strict';
var weatherAppCtr =angular.module('weatherAppCtr',[]);

weatherAppCtr.controller('weatherCtrl',["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
  $scope.weatherDetails =[];
  $http.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mayurah/5f4a6b18b1aa8c26910f/raw/countriesToCities.json').success(function(response){
    $scope.countryListData = response;
    for(var country in $scope.countryListData){
      for( var city in $scope.countryListData[country]){
        $scope.cityList.push($scope.countryListData[country][city] + "-"+country)
      }
    }
  });

  $scope.$watch("cityName", function(newValue,oldValue){

  });
  $scope.addCity =function(){
    var selectedCity =$scope.cityName;
    $scope.populateWeatherDetails(selectedCity);
  };
  $scope.populateWeatherDetails =function(selectedCity){
    if($scope.selectedCities.indexOf(selectedCity)> -1){
    alert ("City is already loaded");

    }
    else{
      $scope.selectedCities.push(selectedCity);
      var successResponse = function(response){
        if(response.query.results.weather.rss.channel.title ==="Yahoo! Weather - Error"){
          alert("City not found");
        }
        else{
          $scope.weatherDetails.push(response.query.results.weather.rss.channel);
        }
      };
      var selectedCityName =selectedCity.split("-")[0];
      var selectedCountryName =selectedCity.split("-")[1];

      var resultUrl ="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=use%20'http%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fyql%2Fyql-tables%2Fraw%2Fmaster%2Fweather%2Fweather.bylocation.xml'" + 
            "%20as%20we%3Bselect%20*%20from%20we%20where%20location%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent(selectedCityName) + "%22%20and%20unit%3D'c'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";

      $http.get(resultUrl).success(successResponse);
      $scope.cityName="";
    }
  };

  $scope.getConditionClass =function(conditionCode){
    var code=parseInt(conditionCode, 10);
     switch(code){
            case 0: return "wi-tornado";
            case 1: return "wi-day-sunny";
            case 2: return "wi-hurricane";
            case 3: return "wi-thunderstorm";
            case 4: return "wi-thunderstorm";
            case 5: return "wi-day-rain-mix";
            case 6: return "wi-rain-wind";
            case 7: return "wi-snow-wind";
            case 8: return "wi-sprinkle";
            case 9: return "wi-sprinkle";
            case 10: return "wi-storm-showers";
            case 11: return "wi-showers";
            case 12: return "wi-showers";
            case 13: return "wi-showers";
            case 14: return "wi-showers";
            case 15:
            case 16:
            case 17:
            case 18: 
            case 19: 
            case 20: return "wi-snow";
            case 21: return "wi-day-haze";
            case 22:
            case 23:
            case 24: return "wi-cloudy-windy";
            case 25:
            case 26:
            case 27:
            case 28: return "wi-cloudy"
            case 29:
            case 30: return "wi-cloudy-windy"
            case 31:
            case 32:
            case 33:
            case 34:
            case 35:
            case 36: return "wi-day-sunny"
            case 37:
            case 38:
            case 39: return "wi-thunderstorm";
            case 40:
            case 41:
            case 42:
            case 43:
            case 44:
            case 45:
            case 46:
            case 47: return "wi-showers";

            default: return "wi-day-sunny";
        }  
    };


  $scope.cityList=[];
  $scope.selectedCities =[];
  $scope.populateWeatherDetails("Nairobi - Kenya")
}]);

}(window));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your appmodule.js just add it

```
var weatherapp = angular.module('weatherapp', ["ui.router","weatherAppCtr"])
                                                           ^
                                                         Here
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to do this, you can use two modules and include one in an other or use the same module for the config and your controller like this in Appcontroller.js :

Delete this line :

```
var weatherAppCtr = angular.module('weatherAppCtr',[]);
```

And modifiy this one to have the same module for your controller and your config :

```
 weatherapp.controller('weatherCtrl',["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
   ^Here
```